# Correct "nice" POSIX scheduling priority for batch processing program

Tags: linux, macos, unix, process, posix

I am working on a bulk image processing program which does not require user attention and need to choose a priority level for this process.

The superuser is able to set values from PRI_MIN (-20) to PRI_MAX (+20) and normal users can set from 0 to PRI_MAX. The default level is zero.

On Mac OS X 10.11, the `man nice(1)` documentation discusses priority levels and notes conformance to POSIX.2 (IEEE Std 1003.2-1992). However this documentation is [not publicly available](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1003.2-1992.html) and, also, has [been superseded](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1003.2-1992.html).

Other than randomly picking a number between 0 and 20 inclusive, is there a prescribed, meaningful way to choose the priority level based on some POSIX or Mac standard?

Comment: I am asking from the perspective of the person writing the software, not the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The batch processing priority is often OS specific and generally is not covered by POSIX.

Check the [`sched.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sched.h.html) header, and the function [`sched_get_priority_min`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sched_get_priority_max.html). This is a newer more advanced interface, compared to the `nice`.

Linux additionally supports `SCHED_BATCH` and `SCHED_IDLE` policies, while Mac OS X provides entirely different interface called [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html) with `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND`.